# Let $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. Prove that if $a > 1$, then for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n > 1$, it holds that $a < a^{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Let $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. Prove that if $a > 1$, then for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n > 1$, it holds that $a < a^{n}$.

While using the direct method for this proof, I would take $a > 1$ and $a^{n} > a^{n-1}$.

However I don't know how to write a formal proof and some help would be great.

Comment: You can prove it by induction on $n$.  For that, you can use Archimedes' Axiom for real numbers.

Comment: Conider proving $a(a^{n-1}-1)>0$ using induction instead.

Comment: $$\frac{d}{da}(a^n-a)= na^{n-1}-1\geq n - 1 > 0$$ using calculus and $a^n>1$ for all natural $n$.